# Panels not scrolling

Tags: asp.net, panels

I am not sure what has happened here, but I have 3 panels, and these 3 panels are nested inside one large, thus:

```
<asp:panel id="pnlMain" runat="server" Height="60%" Width="100%">

  <div id="div1">
    <asp:panel id="panel1" runat="server" Height="100%" width="100"
        scrollbars="vertical"/>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <asp:panel id="panel2" runat="server" Height="100%" width="100"
        scrollbars="vertical"/>
  </div>

  <div id="div3">
    <asp:panel id="panel3" runat="server" Height="100%" width="100"
        scrollbars="vertical"/>
  </div>

</asp:panel>
```

What is happening is that when I add my gridviews to these nested panels, the panel is just getting larger, the scroll bars are not scrolling, in other words the panels are stretching rather than their height staying fixed.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your heights to a fixed number rather than 100%.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the size as a pixel stop the panel fitting any browser size resolution?